# Deleting a node that has two subtree/node

Tags: c

I have problem deleting a node that has two subtree. I managed to delete node when the node has left or right subtree, but i got segmentation fault when i tried to delete a node that has two sub tree. I need some help. I have a function to search and return a node that to be deleted and I have function return minimum value from subtree. Both functions works

```
bool tree_delete(tree_t *t, void *key){

 node_t **find = findNode(t, key); 

  if(*find != NULL){

    if((*find) -> left == NULL && (*find) -> right == NULL){
      free(*find);
      return true; 
      }
    else if ((*find) -> left != NULL && (*find) -> right == NULL){
      node_t *temp = *find; 
      *find = (*find) -> left ; 
      free(temp); 
      return true; 


    }
    else if ((*find)-> left == NULL && (*find) -> right !=NULL){
      node_t *temp = *find; 
      *find = (*find) -> right;
      free(temp); 
      return true; 
    }
    else{

      // problem in this part of the code
      node_t **min  = find_min(&(*find) -> right);
      *find = *min; 
      free(*min);
      return true; 

    }
  }
}
```

---

I've updated my code like this, but still getting segfault -

```
 node_t *temp = *find;
  node_t **min  = find_min(&(*find)-> right); 
  (*min) ->right = (*find)->right;
  (*min) ->left = (*find)->left;
  *find = *min;
  free(temp);
  node_t **min2 = find_min(&(*find) -> right); 
  free(*min2); 
  *min2 = NULL; 
  return true;
```

Comment: Why do you have double pointers (`node_t **find`) used dereferenced (`(*find)`)?

Comment: how come you're only checking the right side of the tree in the else

Comment: yes, i am using double pinter. find_min function find minumum value from right sub tree of the node that suppose to be deleted

Comment: 1) `free(*find);` --> `free(*find);*find = NULL;`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, i wanna replace *find, it is a root of subtree, if i free *find, it does not work

Comment: I can not understand why You say such a thing to my comment.

Comment: what is such thing?

Comment: @granmirupa no, still i got segfault

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm assuming the tree is sorted and the `*min` is a leaf node.

This should be correct:

```
else{
  node_t *temp = *find;
  node_t **min  = find_min(&(*find) -> right); 
  (*min) ->right = (*find) ->right;
  (*min) ->left = (*find) ->left;
  *find = *min;
  free(temp);
  // some more operation --> read below
  return true; 
}
```

**N.B.** Moreover you need to get the old parent of `*min` and put its left child (the old `*min`) to NULL

In the below example you are removing the "7" and "8" is the min element.
You need to put `"9"->left = NULL;`

[image]

Comment: what do you mean " *min and put its left child (the old *min) to NULL"

Comment: @DanielNilles look the picture.. You're putting "8" as the new root.. So "9"->left needs to be NULL

Comment: @DanielNilles if it worked please set the answer as solved

Comment: @gramripupa, how to find Predecessor of node 8 ?

Comment: @DanielNilles you need to search in the subtree till one of the childs is equal to (*min)

Comment: @DanielNilles that's not how I explained. It's not what I said. Why are you freeing min2? Please read again what I wrote..